# move_uploded_file is not working while using curl in php

Tags: php, mysql, curl

**Following are the code in curl i'm sending images and reg number...**

```
char url[]="xyz.com/imm/application.php?";
    char curlErr[2*CURL_ERROR_SIZE]={0};
    CURL *curl=NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *post=NULL, *last=NULL;
    FILE *fp=NULL;


    fp = fopen(SEND_DATA_RESPONSE_PATH, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
printf("%s:unable to open %s\n", __func__, SEND_DATA_RESPONSE_PATH);
        return -1;
    }
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
printf("%s:unable to init curl\n", __func__);
        return -2;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, fp);

    curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "registerNumber",
        CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, studentDetails.regNo, CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "studentPhoto",
        CURLFORM_FILE, PHOTO_PATH, CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "parentImage",
        CURLFORM_FILE, SIG_PATH, CURLFORM_END);


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curlErr);
    res=curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_formfree(post);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    if (res != 0) {
printf("%s:Curl error: %s\n", __func__, curlErr);
        return -3;
    }
    return 0;
```

**After this.. in application.php page i'm trying to get rer number and images and uplod this image to server.. But move_uploaded_file is not working...**

```
$regNum=$_POST['registerNumber'];
 $std_img_tmp_name=$_FILES['studentPhoto']['tmp_name'];
 $std_img_name = $_FILES['studentPhoto']['name'];
 $std_img_fileSize = $_FILES['studentPhoto']['size'];
 $std_img_fileType = $_FILES['studentPhoto']['type'];
 $sig_tmp_name=$_FILES['signatureImage']['tmp_name'];
 $sig_name = $_FILES['signatureImage']['name'];
 $sig_fileSize = $_FILES['signatureImage']['size'];
 $sig_fileType = $_FILES['signatureImage']['type'];

 $target_path = "../uploads/";

 $student_img_name=$target_path.$std_img_name;
 $signature_name=$target_path.$sig_name;

$photo_status=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["studentPhoto"]['tmp_name'], $student_img_name); 
$sig_image_status=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["signatureImage"]["tmp_name"], $signature_name); 

if($photo_status==FALSE || $sig_image_status==FALSE)
{
    echo "<result><error>Unable to upload photo</error></result>";
    exit(); 
}
```

It's throwing a error.... how to solve this...

Comment: unable to upload photo ......

Comment: when i'm trying to echo $_FILES['studentPhoto']['tmp_name'];
 its displaying temp file name.. but when i'm moving to upload folder its not moving the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks correct. Check and make sure uploads directory has the right permissions.